# Errors of my VBA coding in copying and pasting data from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy data whose file location stated on cells I4,I5 to the file whose file location stated on cells B4,B5.  The data should be copied from one workbook to another workbook but it shows me runtime error '9'. Anyone knows what is the problem?

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim PFile As String
Dim PFilePath As String

FilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
FileName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
PFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I4")
PFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I5")

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(PFilePath & PFile)
Set y = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)

'Now, copy what you want from x:
 x.Sheets("DTH&TPDClaims List").Range("A1:W9999").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
 y.Sheets("DTH&TPDClaims List").Range("A1:W9999").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: I would run a check to see if your workbooks open using `If Not x Is Nothing Then`. I would also check the sheet names. You haven't used the greatest naming convention so it will allow for room for error. Also when setting your `String` values use either `.Text` or `.Value`. I prefer to use `.Text` when working with `String` type.

Comment: There is an error on FilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4"). Should I have to activate Worksheets("Sheet1") or anything else?

Comment: No.  You never need to Activate.  But it is good practice to use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Text` as this will prevent problems with formulae, URLs, etc).

Comment: Make sure that you actually have a sheet with the name `Sheet1`. Also qualify the workbook using `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the error is still there. This my third sub and I created a new workbook at my first sub. Does it mean that I have to create a workbook coding in front of Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")? I have no ideas how to qualify my original workbook as a name so that I can use in the workbook coding. Any ideas? After I added ThisWorkbook, the error is still there. Thank you!

Comment: yehan, are the worksheets/cells containing the file path information in an *open* workbook? If yes, is this the workbook containing the macro? Or are they in one of the workbooks you're trying to open?

Comment: the worksheets/cells containing the file path information in an open workbook, which is the workbook that contains the VBA code I'm looking at. Yes, this workbook contains a macro.